# Xamarin CarouselView Not Displayed

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am attempting to use CarouselView for the first time and is kind of struck with it. I have XAML defined as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView"
             x:Class="cSixty.Xam.Views.MainPage"
             Title="MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Name"  HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        <cv:CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Zoos}">
            <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />

                </DataTemplate>
            </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </cv:CarouselView>
    </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The ViewModel has a Collection defined as follows.

```
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        Zoos = new ObservableCollection<Zoo>
            {
                new Zoo
                {
                    Name = "Woodland Park Zoo"
                },
                    new Zoo
                {
                    Name = "Cleveland Zoo"
                    },
                new Zoo
                {
                    Name = "Phoenix Zoo"
                }
            };

    }
```

Where Zoo is defined as

```
public class Zoo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My issue is that the Carousel just doesn't show up. Its all empty. Could someone guide me ?

Comment: You defined `Zoos` as public property?

Comment: Yes, its public 
 public ObservableCollection<Zoo> Zoos{ get; set; }

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working, just thought will share it in case someone else runs into same situation.

You need install the Nuget Package in your Droid Project (or whatever platform you are using) as well. Previously, I had installed in my Portable Library only.