# Xamarin Empty CarouselView

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add a carousel view to my xamarin forms cross platform app:

here's my XAML code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView" 
    x:Class="test.Pagina3">


    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="300" 
            HeightRequest="190">
            <cv:CarouselView x:Name="carosello" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
                <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate>

                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">

                            <Label x:Name = "label_nome" 
                                Text = "{Binding nome}" 
                                TextColor = "Black" />

                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>

                </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </cv:CarouselView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

and here is my view model code:

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Pagina3 : ContentPage
    {
        public Pagina3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //ViewModelSpesa spesa = new ViewModelSpesa();
            List<Oggetto_spesa> list = new List<Oggetto_spesa>();

            list.Add(new Oggetto_spesa("jsna", 123.1, "13sd"));
            carosello.ItemsSource = list;
        }

    }
}
```

the result is an empty yellow view, I've seen other questions such as this:
[Xamarin CarouselView Not Displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45780641/xamarin-carouselview-not-displayed)

with no luck, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: For the binding with your list to work you need to ensure you can "get" it: List<Oggetto_spesa> list { get; } = new List<Oggetto_spesa>();
Also, you're only adding one item to your list at the moment - so you'll only have 1 thing to view

Comment: got an error with that declaration "; expected" , i want to see just one item because is just a test...

Comment: Sorry, should of mentioned you should declare it outside of the constructor, and make it public

Comment: Still no luck: with 2 items I have a weird scroll-like view but no label...                I think the problem is the framework itself

Comment: is "label_nome" within your Oggetto_spesa class set with public and get?
I'm obviously suspecting a binding issue, what happens if you simply change the text assignment in xaml to a random string?

Comment: it was private with gets ,now it works Thank you so so much

Comment: No problem. Glad it's working for you

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is my Xaml code:-

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage
        xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        x:Class="MyCairns.Views.ZoomReportImage"
       xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView"
           x:Name="ZoomPage"  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyCairns"
        Title="{local:Copy ViewPhoto}" >
    <StackLayout x:Name="stackcarosel" >
        <cv:CarouselView x:Name="CarouselZoos"   ItemsSource="{Binding ImagesZoom}" >
            <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Source}" />                    
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </cv:CarouselView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Here is my Xaml.cs Code:-

```
ObservableCollection<GalleryImage> _images = new ObservableCollection<GalleryImage>();
```

_images .Add(new GalleryImage("jsna", 123.1, "13sd"));

PageViewModel = new PageViewModel(_images);

Here is my View Model Code:-

```
    ObservableCollection<GalleryImage> _images = new ObservableCollection<GalleryImage>();


    public ObservableCollection<GalleryImage> ImagesZoom{get => _images;}

    public PageViewModel(ObservableCollection<GalleryImage> _images)
    {
        this._images = _images;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding comments as an answer so this can be marked as completed:

You carousel view code is fine, the bindings need to be marked as public.

Change

```
List<Oggetto_spesa> list = new List<Oggetto_spesa>();
```

to

```
public List<Sensors> list { get; } = new List<Sensors>();
```

and be sure to move it out of the constructor.

Also in your "Oggetto_spesa" class ensure that "label_nome" is public.

Just for future reference, if you want to update any of the details on the carousel views (and I assume you do since you're using Bindings), you should change List to ObservableCollection [ObservableCollection<> vs. List<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196968/observablecollection-vs-list)